# Can you construct a coutable local base in the space of continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $(C,\tau)$ be the topological vector space of all complex continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with seminorms $p_x(f)=|f(x)|$, $x\in [0,1]$. We have known $(C,\tau)$ is not metrizable,but how could I prove that $(C,\tau)$ has no countable local base? Do there exist a constructive proof?

Comment: [A Hausdorff topological vector space is metrizable iff it has a countable local base.](http://books.google.com/books?id=9kXY742pABoC&pg=PA28)

Comment: But is there a constructive proof?Associate to each $p\in\mathcal{P}$ and to each positive integer $n$ the set $$V(p,n)=\{f\in C:p_x(f)<\frac{1}{n}.$$ Frow this we can construct a subbase,but how about a countable local base?

Comment: Take the sets $V(\max\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}, n)$ where $p_1,\dots,p_k \in \mathcal{P}$.

Comment: Under this construction,you get another seminorm family which is clsed under $max$,then it exactly forms a coutable local base.That's to say,$\tau$ can be metrizable if we construct a suitable seminorm family.Right?

Comment: Yes. If $\mathcal{P}$ is a countable family of seminorms then we can close it under taking the maxima of finite families and get another countable family of seminorms $\mathcal{P'}$ inducing the same topology. Your construction then yields a countable local base, not only a subbase.